# Parse error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parse-error

The following code:

```
import IO
import System(getArgs)

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let l = length args
    if l == 0
        putStrLn "foo"
    else
        putStrLn "bar"
```

generates a parse error for the if-else clause. I have tried using curly braces to no avail.
Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to demonstrate my comment to Mark's answer,

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let l = length args
    if l == 0
      then putStrLn "foo"
      else putStrLn "bar"
```

is legal Haskell.

---

With GHC 7.0's [`{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/836) extension, you can even get away with

```
class IfThenElse a b c d | a b c -> d where
    ifThenElse :: a -> b -> c -> d
instance IfThenElse Bool a a a where
    ifThenElse True = const
    ifThenElse False = flip const
instance (Monad m, IfThenElse a (m b) (m b) (m b))
      => IfThenElse (m a) (m b) (m b) (m b) where
    ifThenElse = liftM ifThenElse

main =
    if liftM null getArgs
      then putStrLn "foo"
      else putStrLn "bar"
```

(Shamelessly aped from [blog.n-sch.de](http://blog.n-sch.de/2010/11/27/rebindable-if-then-else-expressions/).)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. <s>You're missing the `in` part of [the `let-in` clause](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/letQexpressions_reference.html)</s> (See (and accept) [@ephemient's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320634/parse-error-in-haskell/4320892#4320892))
2. You're missing the `then` part of [the `if-then-else` clause](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/conditionalQexpression_reference.html)

So it could look like:

```
import IO import System(getArgs)

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let l = length args in
        if l == 0 then
            putStrLn "foo"
        else
            putStrLn "bar"
```

Comment: Inside a `do`, you actually don't need the `in` after a `let`; just go back to the `do`'s indentation.  See http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14